# Hadoop : Number of input records for reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there anyway by which each reducer process could determine the number of elements or records it has to process ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the number of values associated with a given key in your reducer class?

Comment: @ryanbwork yes. BTW, I am under the impression that each reducer would work with a single unique key and its associated values right ??

Comment: @ryanbwork Can't see your answer.

Comment: @ryanbwork it is not correct. The reducer will get a single unique key **at a time** but a single reducer will get multiple keys before the map/reduce is finished

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz thanks for clarification; so a single reducer instance is reused for all the keys sent to a given reducer node?

Comment: @ryanbwork not exactly a node can have several reducer slots and a given map/reduce job may use more than one slot on a given node. It is guaranteed that a single reducer will get all the relevant data (i.e. everything grouped by a key)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz is slot == instance? And if so, doesn't this mean that a given reducer may process multiple sets of K/V pairs (assuming # keys > # slots).

Comment: slot if a potential instance. Hadoop decides how many slots a given map/reduce job would get (based on number of reducers needed, the priority etc). Same goes for for mappers by the way. A slot assigned to a job is an instance and it may get and processes multiple K/array of values (as grouped by the mappers/combiners)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz thanks again for clarification, removed my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer class must extend the MapReducer Reduce class:

`Reducer<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>`

and then must implement the reduce method using the KEYIN/VALUEIN arguments specified in the extended Reduce class

`reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, 
 org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)`

The values associated with a given key can be counted via

```
int count = 0;
Iterator<VALUEIN> it = values.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  it.Next();
  count++;
}
```

Though I'd propose doing this counting along side your other processing as to not make two passes through your value set.

EDIT

Here's an example vector of vectors that will dynamically grow as you add to it (so you won't have to statically declare your arrays, and hence don't need the size of the values set). This will work best for non-regular data (IE the number of columns is not the same for every row in your input csv file), but will have the most overhead.

```
Vector table = new Vector();

Iterator<Text> it = values.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){

  Text t = it.Next();
  String[] cols = t.toString().split(",");   

  int i = 0;
  Vector row = new Vector(); //new vector will be our row
  while(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cols[i])){
    row.addElement(cols[i++]); //here were adding a new column for every value in the csv row
  }

  table.addElement(row);
}
```

Then you can access the Mth column of the Nth row via

```
table.get(N).get(M);
```

Now, if you knew the # of columns would be set, you could modify this to use a Vector of arrays which would probably be a little faster/more space efficient.

Comment: I already had thought of this technique. But keeping in mind the enormous amount of data (~ 3mil per key), I had to abandon it. The prob ofcourse is that this Iterable does not have a "size" method to know the size of data. Any other suggestions ???

Comment: @stholy can you give me a sense of the type of processing you're doing? It may be possible to get the sum of subsets in your mapper (or  possibly in a combiner) before sending these sets to the reducer(s).

Comment: The input of the job is csv file with around 4mil records. Each mapper would emit last_field<key> and all_fields<value>. The reducer has to load all the <values> into a 2d string array. Therefore, to load them into the 2d array, i need the array limits, i.e., number of rows(values per key) and columns(fields).

Comment: Why not use dynamically allocated arrays / vectors?

Comment: Can you give an example ?? I think I am using the wrong data structure.. Pls suggest alternative..

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - ahead of time no, the reducer has no knowledge of how many values are backed by the iterable. The only way you can do this is to count as you iterate, but you can't then re-iterate over the iterable again.

Long answer - backing the iterable is actually a sorted byte array of the serialized key / value pairs. The reducer has two comparators - one to sort the key/value pairs in key order, then a second to determine the boundary between keys (known as the key grouper). Typically the key grouper is the same as the key ordering comparator.

When iterating over the values for a particular key, the underlying context examines the next key in the array, and compares to the previous key using the grouping comparator. If the comparator determines they are equal, then iteration continues. Otherwise iteration for this particular key ends. So you can see that you cannot ahead of time determine how may values you will be passed for any particular key.

You can actually see this in action if you create a composite key, say a Text/IntWritable pair. For the compareTo method sort by first the Text, then the IntWritable field. Next create a Comparator to be used as the group comparator, which only considers the Text part of the key. Now as you iterate over the values in the reducer, you should be able to observe IntWritable part of the key changing with each iteration.

Some code i've used before to demonstrates this scenario can be found on this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xhkbESBQ)

Comment: Why can't I iterate over the `Iterable` twice?